# How to know the last preremove symfony listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener, persist

I have several entities with relationships between them, and when I delete an entity related to another entity, the two entities are deleted. This is what I want. However, I would like to know which one is deleted last. So I have a listener "preremove" which is called twice. Once for the first entity, a second time for the second. But I do not know which one is deleted last. Do you have any ideas? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check tables foreign keys. If your tables have OneToMany relation, record which stores foreign key, will be deleted first.

Comment: Thanks for you response, do you know how see which entity depending to other ?

Comment: you can check it on database administration tools and also on ManyToOne relation Many Side entity stores foreign key.